# Create a cron job for importing csv files in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, import, cron, csv

I am trying to schedule a cron job for importing csv files which consists of the product details. But the cron is not working. can anyone help me resolving this issue?

I am using the following code in crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
<job name="cron_csv" instance="Cron\Csv\Cron\Test" method="myCronFunction">
<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
</job>
</group>
</config>
```

And this is my cron fuction :

```
public function myCronFunction()
{
    $file = fopen('var/import/test123.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
if ($file !== false) {

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

// used for updating product stock - and it's important that it's inside the while loop
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

// add logging capability
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/import-new.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row

// enter the min number of data fields you require that the new product will have (only if you want to standardize the import)
$required_data_fields = 3;

while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 3000, ",") ) {

    $data_count = count($row);
    if ($data_count < 1) {
        continue;
    }

    // used for setting the new product data
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');         
    $data = array();
    $data = array_combine($header, $row);

    $sku = $data['sku'];
    if ($data_count < $required_data_fields) {
        $logger->info("Skipping product sku " . $sku . ", not all required fields are present to create the product.");
        continue;
    }

    $name = $data['name'];
    $description = $data['description'];
    $shortDescription = $data['short_description'];
    $qty = trim($data['qty']);
    $price = trim($data['price']);

    try {
        $product->setTypeId('simple') // type of product you're importing
                ->setStatus(1) // 1 = enabled
                ->setAttributeSetId(4) // In Magento 2.2 attribute set id 4 is the Default attribute set (this may vary in other versions)
                ->setName($name)
                ->setSku($sku)
                ->setPrice($price)
                ->setTaxClassId(0) // 0 = None
                ->setCategoryIds(array(2, 3)) // array of category IDs, 2 = Default Category
                ->setDescription($description)
                ->setShortDescription($shortDescription)
                ->setUrlKey($url_key) // you don't need to set it, because Magento does this by default, but you can if you need to
                ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) // Default Website ID
                ->setStoreId(0) // Default store ID
                ->setVisibility(4) // 4 = Catalog & Search
                ->save();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $logger->info('Error importing product sku: '.$sku.'. '.$e->getMessage());
        continue;
    }

    try {
        $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);

        if ($stockItem->getQty() != $qty) {
            $stockItem->setQty($qty);
            if ($qty > 0) {
                $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
            }
            $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $logger->info('Error importing stock for product sku: '.$sku.'. '.$e->getMessage());
        continue;
    }
    unset($product);
}
fclose($file);
}
}
```

Comment: Try this : `php bin/magento cron:run` command if it is working then you need to check your server CRON configuration.

Comment: When I run the `cron:run` it is showing **Ran jobs by schedule**. But the import is not happening. Products are not added to the catalog.

Comment: Check whether entry is happening in Cron table if not it is problem with cron